# Create a string that would let me find out if index.php file is located in any of the directories

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to declare a Regex expression that would let me know if there is at least one 'index.php' phrase, and if is in a directory like such:

```
http://localhost/Contact/Documentation/index.php
Or
http://localhost/Contact/index.php
Or
localhost/Contact/index.php
```

I need to point out that there are no files on the server, I'm just creating URL thing:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]+)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

This is what I got so far:

```
^[\/]([.+]+[\/]{1}(index.php){1})+&
OR // couldn't make neither work
^(.*/)+(index.php){1}&
```

I need this so I can redirect current page like so:

```
# link to index.php will link to home directory
RedirectMatch 302 ^[\/]([.+]+[\/]{1}(index.php){1})+& http://localhost/
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, I try to have this because I would like to treat each ' / ' in a query string as a ' = '. But what happens is t hat when I create links, such as index.php, it redirects me as a directory within whatever url points to, and not the index i want in 'http://localhost/index.php'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to redirect all requests to `index.php` to the server root location; you can try the following:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^([^/]+/)+index.php$ http://localhost/index.php
```

Comment: I can't seem to match it according to your code, and my code ;((http://.*/)+(index\.php)); from this website http://regex101.com/r/jC5qP6/1

Comment: Now, even touhhg I do match the entire regex I still cannot redirect to the / directory. Any ieas why?

Comment: You __do not__ need to use `http` part in `RedirectMatch` directive.